# Are we held accountable for our thoughts

Tags: hadith

Assalamualaikum,  my question is are we held accountable for our intenational thought,  if we don't believe in that not speak about that or not acted up on that .

Answer (score 1):

Al-Bukhaari (6491) and Muslim (131) narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (PBUH) said:

> “Allah decreed good deeds and bad deeds, then He explained that. Whoever
> thinks of doing a good deed then does not do it, Allah will write it
> down as one complete good deed. If he thinks of doing a good deed and
> then does it, Allah will write it
> down between ten and seven hundred fold, or many more. If he thinks of
> doing a bad deed then he does not do it, Allah will write it down as
> one complete good deed, and if he thinks of it then does it, Allah
> will write it down as one bad deed.”

Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah, that the Prophet (PHUH) said:

> “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah for
> whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or
> speak of it.”

Answer (score 0):

No you are not accountable for your thoughts if you don't act on them as long as your intention "nia" is following allah then you are good to go.